# Compiling TCL 7.6.2 using gcc 3.4.5

Tags: gcc, compilation, tcl

I am compiling TCL 7.6p2 using gcc 3.4.5. I am using a CentOS 5.5. I get the following error during the make command:

```
./../generic/tclPosixStr.c: In function `Tcl_ErrnoId':
./../generic/tclPosixStr.c:340: error: duplicate case value
./../generic/tclPosixStr.c:328: error: previously used here
./../generic/tclPosixStr.c: In function `Tcl_ErrnoMsg':
./../generic/tclPosixStr.c:787: error: duplicate case value
./../generic/tclPosixStr.c:775: error: previously used here
make: *** [tclPosixStr.o] Error 1
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to build such an ancient version?  The current stable release is 8.5.9 available from http://tcl.tk/software/tcltk/8.5.html

Comment: One version of the eggdrop FAQ still recommends it apparently. It's telling that that particular revision of the FAQ is over 10 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use an ***ancient*** version that's not been supported for many many years. As such, your best approach is to hack the source code to comment out the offending cases from those `switch` statements. *Or switch to something that someone can be bothered to support* (but that's your call).

In detail: It appears that EOPNOTSUPP is the same value as ENOTSUP; comment out each group of three lines (or at least the lines with the `case`; the surrounding `#ifdef` machinery isn't harmful) associated with EOPNOTSUPP to make the problem go away. Or you can backport the change that's present in all non-antediluvian versions, which is to improve the `#ifdef` lines to this:

```
#if defined(EOPNOTSUPP) &&  (!defined(ENOTSUP) || (ENOTSUP != EOPNOTSUPP))
```

Don't bother reporting this as a bug though. *Tcl 7.6p2 is not supported.*

Comment: I commented out all the lines with case associated with EOPNOTSUPP and was successfully able to compile. Thanks!